# Anyone use CFAllocatorSetDefault succesfully in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiwebview, core-foundation

I wish to replace the default `CFAllocator` in my iPhone app with my own implementation. I want to control the memory allocated by the `UIWebView` since it seems to hold on to so much memory after loading a website and that memory still lingers around when the `UIWebView` is released.

After I call `CFAllocatorSetDefault` I get an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` exception when the next allocation occurs.

The exception seems to happen inside of a call to `CFRetain` (done in the simulator but the same thing happens on a device):

```
CoreFoundation`CFRetain:
0x1c089b0:  pushl  %ebp
0x1c089b1:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1c089b3:  pushl  %edi
0x1c089b4:  pushl  %esi
0x1c089b5:  subl   $16, %esp
0x1c089b8:  calll  0x1c089bd                 ; CFRetain + 13
0x1c089bd:  popl   %edi
0x1c089be:  movl   8(%ebp), %esi
0x1c089c1:  testl  %esi, %esi
0x1c089c3:  jne    0x1c089db                 ; CFRetain + 43
0x1c089c5:  int3   
0x1c089c6:  calll  0x1d66a00 ; symbol stub for: getpid <- EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT subcode=0x0)
0x1c089cb:  movl   %eax, (%esp)
0x1c089ce:  movl   $9, 4(%esp)
0x1c089d6:  calll  0x1d66a4e                 ; symbol stub for: kill
0x1c089db:  movl   (%esi), %eax
0x1c089dd:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x1c089df:  je     0x1c08a17                 ; CFRetain + 103
0x1c089e1:  cmpl   1838519(%edi), %eax
0x1c089e7:  je     0x1c08a17                 ; CFRetain + 103
0x1c089e9:  movl   4(%esi), %ecx
0x1c089ec:  shrl   $8, %ecx
0x1c089ef:  andl   $1023, %ecx
0x1c089f5:  cmpl   1834423(%edi,%ecx,4), %eax
0x1c089fc:  je     0x1c08a17                 ; CFRetain + 103
0x1c089fe:  movl   1766575(%edi), %eax
0x1c08a04:  movl   %eax, 4(%esp)
0x1c08a08:  movl   %esi, (%esp)
0x1c08a0b:  calll  0x1d665c8                 ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
```

Comment: Note that WebKit won't use CF's allocator anyway. It has its own.

Comment: @Catfish_Man Are you sure?  See my updated answer.

Comment: Quite certain. It may do some incidental allocations with CF's allocator, but the bulk of the actual WebCore/JSCore allocations use FastMalloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

Core Foundation has a bug that makes `CFAllocatorSetDefault` useless.

Specifically, if you study the implementation of `_CFRuntimeCreateInstance` in [`CFRuntime.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFRuntime.c), you'll see that:

- If it's not using the system default allocator, it tries to retain the allocator.
- If it's been passed `NULL` as its `allocator` argument, it will try to retain that `NULL` instead of the current default allocator.
- The call to `CFRetain` will therefore crash.

What it **should** do is retain the current default allocator when it's given `NULL` as its `allocator` argument.

Since lots of functions in Apple's own libraries apparently pass `NULL` (or `kCFAllocatorDefault`, which is also a null pointer) to functions that create a Core Foundation object, you're bound to crash quickly if you change the default allocator at all.

My test case: I created a new, single-view iPhone app.  I added one line to `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CFAllocatorSetDefault(kCFAllocatorMalloc);
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The app crashes during startup on the simulator and on my test device, in `CFRetain`, with `EXC_BREAKPOINT`, with a null pointer as the function argument.

### ORIGINAL

You are passing a null pointer to `CFRetain`.  If this has anything to do with your custom allocator, you need to post more details, like the full call stack when the exception occurs.

In your disassembly listing, the instructions from `0x1c089b0` through `0x1c089bd` are the function prologue.

At `0x1c089be`, the `movl 8(%ebp), %esi` instruction loads the first function argument from the stack into `%esi`.

At `0x1c089c1`, the `testl %esi, %esi` instruction sets the processor flags based on the value of `%esi`.  In particular, it sets the Z (zero) flag to 1 if `%esi` contains zero, and sets the Z flag to 0 if `%esi` contains anything else.

At `0x1c089c3`, the `jne 0x1c089db` instruction jumps if the `ne` condition is true.  The `ne` condition is true when the Z flag is 0 and false when the Z flag is 1.  So this instruction jumps when `%esi` (the first argument) is non-zero, and falls through when `%esi` is zero.

At `0x1c089c5`, the `int3` instruction raises a `SIGTRAP` signal with exception code `EXC_BREAKPOINT`.  The `int3` instruction is normally stuffed into a program by the debugger when you set a breakpoint.  In this case, it was hardcoded in the program at compile-time.

Thus, you are getting this exception because you are passing a null pointer to `CFRetain`.

You can also look at the source code of `CFRetain` if you like.  It is in [`CFRuntime.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFRuntime.c):

```
CFTypeRef CFRetain(CFTypeRef cf) {
    if (NULL == cf) { CRSetCrashLogMessage("*** CFRetain() called with NULL ***"); HALT; }
    if (cf) __CFGenericAssertIsCF(cf);
    return _CFRetain(cf, false);
}
```

So the very first thing `CFRetain` does is test whether its argument is `NULL`.  `CGSetCrashLogMessage` is a macro defined in [`CoreFoundation_Prefix.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CoreFoundation_Prefix.h) that does nothing.  `HALT` is a macro defined in [`CFInternal.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/CFInternal.h):

```
    #define HALT do {asm __volatile__("int3"); kill(getpid(), 9); } while (0)
```

As you can see, `HALT` has a hard-coded `int3` instruction.  Then it calls `kill(getpid(), 9)`.  This matches your disassembly listing.

Comment: Here's the partial stack when the exception occurred:
`    frame #0: 0x01c169c6 CoreFoundation`CFRetain + 22
    frame #1: 0x01c17917 CoreFoundation`_CFRuntimeCreateInstance + 391
    frame #2: 0x01c202aa CoreFoundation`__CFArrayInit + 202
    frame #3: 0x01c201d0 CoreFoundation`__CFArrayCreateMutable0 + 32
    frame #4: 0x035c2e52 WebCore`WKViewAddSubview + 114
    frame #5: 0x0356f316 WebCore`-[WAKView addSubview:] + 102`
The native CFRetain is called and probably doesn't like something that my allocator created early on.

Comment: I have filed a bug (#14185614) at http://bugreport.apple.com.  If you want this to be fixed, you should also file a bug.

Comment: That should be fixed in Mavericks/iOS 7, fwiw

Comment: @Catfish_Man I can also confirm that this works perfectly in iOS7-9 (and crashes on iOS 6)